# Launch Activity /Service of an applications from two applications with different signing keys

Tags: android, signature, samsung-mobile, android-permissions

I have an Android App A whose activities/services are launched by App B both signed with same release engineering keys. I have added Signature permission check for ensuring no other app signed with diff certificates can access App A functions.

Now I had to create Samsung specific App C ,(App C = App B + Samsung APIs)  which needs to be signed with Samsung Specific keys to get installed on Samsung devices.
So now App C wont be able to communicate  with App A as signing certificates wont match.
The security measures have backfired on me this way :D

Is there any way i can mention in App A that along with App B , only App C signed with Samsung keys can communicate with it ?

Samsung 4.0 SDK introduces ELM which eliminates the need to sign your app with Samsung keys. But my client wants to Support Samsung 3.0 SDK ie From Android 4.0 onwards.

**EDIT :-**
Also App A will reply to App B or App C using broadcasts. Again i want only these apps to receive the broadcast and not others . This seems to be a more difficult task.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: Why do you have App A and App B in the first place? Why is this not just one app?

Comment: Because App A is derived from Opensource code . so i chose to make it a separate app which is opensource.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. There can be a billion copies of App A with a billion signing keys. App B cannot interoperate with most of them, let alone App C. So, I'll ask again: Why do you have App A and App B in the first place? Why is this not just one app?

Comment: So App B was developed which needed support of a feature supported by an existing opensource app. I could not directly include code from open source app in app B as i would have to make app B opensource due to licensing. I needed to modify the open source app for my requirements. So i chose to create opensource app A with required modifications. I call services of this app from App B .

Comment: I completely agree with what you say but just wanted to confirm of any possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you retain a qualified attorney, as you may or may not be interpreting the open source license the way a judge and jury will if you get sued.

Beyond that, you can see whether `Binder.getCallingUid()` in App A returns the UID of App B/C for your IPC scenarios. If it does, then you can use `PackageManager` to find out what that app is, then check its public signing key to see if it is the magic signing key of App C.

However:

- Anyone who has the source to App A can modify App A to remove this.
- Anyone who has the source to App A can see the public signing key of App C, which in theory should not be a problem (particularly if they get download App C and examine it themselves anyway).
- I have never tried `getCallingUid()` from an activity.

You can find some book samples related to this in [my book's GitHub repository](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MiscSecurity). I tend to be more concerned about the reverse scenario (App B/C validating that App A is what it should be, and is not some modified version), and so the samples tend to reflect that a bit, but it will give you the code for some of the mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will go through the details in your post.the reverse scenario is also v important to handle.will come up with updates soon

Comment: If App B and App C contains App A public signing key in raw format something like your example does, then they can verify whether the Intent they want to launch is from a Valid App A or not . Do you see any issue in this ? Also i have edited the question to add one more question to it .

Comment: @AlokKulkarni: "Do you see any issue in this ?" -- Apps B and C can themselves be modified to remove this check. "Also i have edited the question to add one more question to it" -- you can try `getCallingUid()` from `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`, as that might work.

Comment: But App B and C are closed source. So that's "officially" not possible. Or did i miss anything here ?

Comment: @AlokKulkarni: Reverse engineering Android apps is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Yes of course. But the use case is say :- App A is authentic and App B is authentic. Both will check each others signatures when communicating. Both will proceed. App A is authentic , App B is not. App A will check signatures and since B is modified , the certificates won't match .(I guess so or this is where i am thinking incorrect) App A wont communicate with App B even if App B removes checks for App A.

Comment: @AlokKulkarni: Correct. You asked "do you see any issue in this?", and I answered it.

Comment: You hv been of great help Mark. I will work on it and post a working code.